# When the action is to move right in CartPole, it moves to the left side. Why it is like that? How can this be resolved?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

In my experiments, I'm using OpenAI's `CartPole-v1` environment. I need to set a state and then perform an action on that state. When I perform a specific action, it does not behave as expected. For example, when the action "Go Right" is used, it moves to the left.

I have a state s=`[ 0.048  0.151 -0.037 -0.265]` and an action: **Go Right** which is **1** according to document.

When I applied the action 1 to the s, I am getting the new state `[-0.016  0.206 -0.029 -0.326]`

It is supposed to move the right side.

Here is the code I tried:

```py
env.reset()
state=[ 0.048  0.151 -0.037 -0.265]
env.state = env.unwrapped.state = state
s, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
print(state,s)
```